# Get many S3 objects public URL in AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS SDK for PHP v3, there's a `\Aws\S3\S3Client` class with `getObjectUrl` method that fetches the public URL for a single object, is there a way I can do that for 1000 objects in a single request? (that's the api limit for one request)

One other problem is that that method actually get the whole object:

```
public function getObjectUrl($bucket, $key)
{
    $command = $this->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key
    ]);

    return (string) \Aws\serialize($command)->getUri();
}
```

It would be better if it'd only get the URL not the object itself because that's a overhead I dont need.